# Injecting different implementations of an interface into different controllers with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have a `IFileSystemService` interface, which defines a set of file & directory management functions. It has an implementation and is injected by Autofac into controllers that need it.

However, for reasons out of our control, we now have a requirement to move one specific part of the website to use database instead of the filesystem, while maintaining the same functionality (i.e., a "lite" version of a filesystem using database for storage). For this, I have created a second implementation of `IFileSystemService`, which works with the DB instead of the actual filesystem.

However, I can't figure out how to tell Autofac to use this second implementation on the specific controller(s) that need it, while leaving the original implementation as the default for all others.

Comment: This isn't quite a common use case, but when you get it, its a headache. Thanks for this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services can be "named" in AutoFac as per https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices

To register the Db implementation of the `IFileSystemService` as a named instance:

`builder.Register<MyDbFileSystemService>().Named<IFileSystemService>("DbFileSystemService");`

Then to get the dependent controller to use the named registration:

`builder.Register(c => new MyControllerWithDbDependency(c.Resolve< IFileSystemService >("DbFileSystemService")))
   .As<Controller>()
   .etc`

In the case of the updated question when this is not feasible due to the large number of additional dependencies, I would do one of the following:

1. Move the IFileSystemService dependency into a property of the controller
2. Abstract the resolution of the IFileSystemService into a factory and dynamically resolve the dependency at runtime
3. Register the concrete IFileSystemService implementations as services for their own specific types and then use specific implementations within the signature of the controller constructor

**IFileSystemService Factory**

```
public class MyControllerWithDbDependency : Controller
{
   MyControllerWithDbDependency(IFileSystemServiceFactory fileSystemServiceFactory,
                                ISomeOtherDependency ...)
   {
      _service = fileSystemServiceFactory.Create("MyDbFileSystemServiceFactory");
   }
}

public interface IFileSystemServiceFactory
{
    IFileSystemServiceFactory Create(string dependencyName);
}

public class AutoFacFileSystemServiceFactory : IFileSystemService
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;

    public AutoFacFileSystemServiceFactory(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        if (componentContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("componentContext");
        _componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public IFileSystemService Create(string dependencyName)
    {
        return _componentContext.ResolveNamed<IFileSystemService>(dependencyName);
    }
}
```

I.e. each controller is responsible for specifying the specific `IFileSystemService` dependency it requires, which in turn means no alteration to the AutoFac configuration for the controllers.

To be honest, I usually only use this technique in situations where the specific type to be resolved is genuinely not known until runtime - unlike in the case of the question where it would be used as a workaround.

Obviously if you have a large number of controllers and a small set of `IFileSystemService` implementations, and if it makes sense from a design perspective, you could push the call to `Create` on the factory to a custom controller base type and save yourself some code duplication.

**Register specific implementations of IFileSystemService as services of themselves**

```
public class MyControllerWithDbDependency : Controller
{
   MyControllerWithDbDependency(MyDbFileSystemService dbFileSystemService,
                                ISomeOtherDependency ...)
   {
      // ...
   }
}

// AutoFac configuration
builder.RegisterType<MyDbFileSystemService>()
   .As<MyDbFileSystemService>()
   .InstancePerWhatever();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultFileSystemService>()
   .As<IFileSystemService>()
   .InstancePerWhatever();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that I need to manually write the resolution call for every constructor argument for each controller that requires the database service? That's not very feasable, as it is a large, interconnected system with easily 20-30 dependencies per controller, which change when code is changed.

Comment: I see. OK then, I guess it will have to be a property on the controller or some resolver/factory in the controller base. I had hoped for something more elegant (i.e., Autofac official), though. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: The codebase Im currently on has quite a few 'AutoFacFactory' factory types that do runtime resolution. If by any chance you find a way todo this natively using AutoFac please update your question with the answer as it would prove very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Just incase you are still working on this - it suddenly occurred to me that there is a third and very obvious way to specify specific implementations. Thats simply to use the specific implementation within the controller constructor and in your AutoFac config register it as a service to itself.

Comment: I thought of that, but it seems that such approach defeats one of the main purposes of using IoC — unit testing. I can't unit test the controller using a mock ``IFileSystemService`` if the specific instance is hard-coded in the constructor. So I went with the idea of a public service property that can be set post-instantiation.

Comment: @MattCaton I was thinking for quite a while for a solution to this and your answer helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @MattCaton could you update your answer to use the ResolveNamed<IFileSystemService>("DbFileSystemService") method? c.Resolve<IFileSystemService>("DbFileSystemService") doesn't work for me